# Sorted by repository vs Sorted by list which one is faster?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

So I wonder which one is faster. sorted by jpa repository or sorted by list ?

```
// sorted by kotlin list function
personRepository
 .findByName(name)
 .map { person -> person.sortedByDescending { it.name } }

// sorted by jpa repository
personRepository
 .findByNameDesc(name)
```

Comment: What happened when you timed both methods?

Comment: It's very close, but I have never tried with large data before.

Comment: its depend list size and index.if name cloumn has index sort in db always better according to my experience

Answer (score 1):

Always sort (and filter and join) in the database if you can.

For small datasets it doesn't matter and if it does you should do your own benchmarks.

For large datasets a database is really tuned for this kind of task.
It may use indexes, may combine sorting, filtering and joining in an efficient way. This becomes especially important when sorting can't happen in memory. With the JVM you'd need to find (or create) special solutions for that while a database returning sorted data that doesn't fit into memory at once is a standard task.